# How to declare Functional Interfaces in static helper classes?

Tags: java, helper, java-8, functional-interface

Given I have the following structure already existing:

```
private void acceptInner(final Path path) throws IOException {
    String newId = FileUtils.readAndModifyFileEntry(StageRename.ID_FILE, "id", 
        idString -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(idString) + 1));
    BaseUtils.moveKeepExtension(path, StageRename.OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, newId);
}
```

Where `FileUtils.readAndModifyFileEntry` is declared as:

```
public static String readAndModifyFileEntry(final Path path, final String entryKey 
    , final UnaryOperator<String> operator) throws IOException { ... }
```

Now I want to move the operator that increases a string value as an integer by one, to a new helper class, I have made two proposals:

```
final public class MapperUtils {
    private MapperUtils() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static String incrementAsInt(final String input) {
        return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(input) + 1);
    }

    public static UnaryOperator<String> incrementAsIntOperator() {
        return input -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(input) + 1);
    }
}
```

Which one would be better, usages are below:

```
String newId = FileUtils.readAndModifyFileEntry(StageRename.ID_FILE, "id",
    MapperUtils::incrementAsInt);
```

versus

```
String newId = FileUtils.readAndModifyFileEntry(StageRename.ID_FILE, "id", 
    MapperUtils.incrementAsIntOperator());
```

Or should I keep both?

One of the advantages of the latter is that I can chain the operator with `andThen()` or `compose()`, but are there any disadvantages to it?

For more reference, I can use the following:

```
((UnaryOperator<String>)MapperUtils::incrementAsInt).andThen(/*something*/)
```

To manually cast it to an operator, but it really looks ugly. However if I provide both, does it then create *an unwanted* method explosion on the codebase?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep both, then the `incrementAsIntOperator()` one can be written as

```
public static UnaryOperator<String> incrementAsIntOperator() {
    return input -> incrementAsInt(input);
}
```

Which tells me that your second one is just a more specialized version of the first one.

I would keep the first method, as that one is more re-usable, and get rid of the second.

Whether or not providing both gives you an "unwanted method explosion" or not is really up to you. Besides that, I can't see any disadvantages of it. Of course you could use this also:

```
String newId = FileUtils.readAndModifyFileEntry(StageRename.ID_FILE, "id", 
    input -> MapperUtils.incrementAsInt(input));
```